# Which should I use 'kept studying so far' or 'have been studying'?

Tags: tenses

I want to say that 'I learned the language in high school for the first time, and I kept studying so far because I was interested in the culture', and it is confusing for me whether I should use 'kept studying' or 'have been studying'.

> I learned Chinese in high school. Since I was interested in Chinese
>   culture, I kept studying the language so far.

or

> I learned Chinese in high school. Because I was interested in Chinese
>   culture, I have been studying the language since then.

Which one do you think sounds better?

Comment: The second example uses perfect grammar, and is well understood. The first is not very clear, because it is not idiomatic. Everything is alright up to the comma. After that I think you mean "I kept studying the language until now". But "continued" would be slightly more elegant than "kept".

Comment: advice: lose the so far. For so long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

> I learned Chinese in high school. Because I was interested in Chinese
>   culture, I have continued studying the language.

This is concise and implies the notion of "since then".  I would even make it a single sentence:

> I learned Chinese in high school and, because I was interested in Chinese
>   culture, I continued studying the language.

This makes the reason for doing so a subordinate clause (not sure if that's the right term) before going on to note what you did because of that.  Although, on reading that, it seems a bit more awkward so I'd be inclined to make it:

> I learned Chinese in high school and, because I was interested in Chinese
>   culture, I continued studying the language after graduation.

So, in retrospect, I like the first one best.

Hope this helps.